# Kivy Reference id by string

Tags: python, string, reference, kivy

I'm building an app that has a grid of 20x20 labels which I've set as ids `id: x1y1, id: x1y2, ... , id: x20y20`  etc. I want to be able to reference the id by passing a string, and modify the text within, using something like;

```
self.ids.name("x1y1").text = "Anything"
```

I've had a look at `dir(self.ids)`, `dir(self.ids.items())` etc but can't seem to figure it out. Is it even possible?

I could create a list of `if statements` like;

```
if str(passedString) == "x1y1":
    self.id.x1y1.text == "Anything"
if str(passedString) == "x1y2":
    self.id.x1y2.text == "Anything"
```

Although I feel that this is incredibly bad practice, also considering I'd need 400 `if statements`! - Sure I could write a little helper-script to write all this code out for me, but again, it's not ideal.

EDIT:
I had a look at;

```
for key, val in self.ids.items():
    print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))
```

Which printed;

```
key=x1y2, val=<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x7f565a34e6d0>
key=x1y3, val=<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x7f565a2c1e88>
```

Might give you/someone an idea of where to go and/or what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to get the reference via a string of the id? You can use normal dictionary lookup (as ids is really a dict).

```
the_string = 'x1y1'
the_reference = self.ids[the_string]
the_reference.text = 'the_new_text'
```

Comment: Oh my!! Why did I not think of this!? Thank you so very much! :D